# How to update references in Visual Studio 'Website' project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, reference

References(like dlls generated by a class library project) do not update automatically in a Visual studio 'Website' project. They do not update even I add them again to the project. How should I update a reference then?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, It was pretty easy. All references are in the 'Bin' folder and all I had to do was to right click on it and then click on 'update reference'.